# Can we build a radio-controlled flying drone using only pre 2000s military tech?

Tags: warfare, aircraft, drone, air-combat

I have a constantly moving floating island that is looking to augment its air force against numerous threats in the sky. Having long run out of resources that don't grow out of crystals or biomaterial on the island, the majority of its resources come from attacking and excavating other islands. Islands which may have native hostile life or intelligent life.

At times multiple islands may be fighting each other or over the same piece of unclaimed land, so control over the skies around the island is critical. The air force operates a range of aircraft. One of which acts like a fleet defense aircraft. Only it defends the island, hurling long range missiles in beyond visual range combat. It combines a powerful radar, high fuel load, and decent computerized technology (pre 2000s military tech). However, due to limited resources and scales of industry they are unable to field many of these fighter platforms. Furthermore, it takes a lot longer to re arm and refuel (does not use normal jet fuel). The large distances involved compound the situation.

In offensive actions the fighter acts as a long range missile platform, however once it expends its ammunition it cannot contribute any offensive action short of EW. To offset this lack of combat capability, drones carrying a load of missiles have been developed. Essentially missile trucks. Once a fighter expends its ammunition, they circle a drone carrier, link with a drone and fly off with one. Essentially a soft reload of sorts.

**While their exists automation on the island, there is no artificial learning, machine learning or deep learning.** They are unable to make transistors at such a small level with the necessary computer science to enable truly autonomous aircraft control that is combat rated. As such the drone is only capable of basic auto pilot and preprogrammed holding patterns. Some even use electromechanical computers. More advanced maneuvers require the use of a human operator who is in a parent fighter aircraft who establishes a link to the drone.

The human operator is essentially a back seater/weapons system officer (WSO) w/ a slightly extended suite. Using a combination of TV and radio guidance, the WSO flies the drone manually from their aircraft. The fighter's onboard radar handles targeting information for the drone. Once a target is locked on, the WSO executes a fire command, from which the drone will fire a missile. The missiles that can be fired include both active and semi active missiles. During such operations, the fighter won't be pulling any aggressive maneuvers except for defensive actions. It'll stay at distance firing away with missiles, aiding older generation fighters. After firing its magazine, the WSO will fly the drone back to an airship and land it while the fighter circles in a holding pattern.

**How feasible would it be to build and field such a drone that utilizes TV and radio command guidance against air targets without access to modern technology?**

Assume technology (military and industrial) is capped to pre 2000s, there is no contemporary AI control or advanced flight mapping technologies that you'd expect to see on either Loyal Wingman or FCAS' drones. All flight maneuvers short of a pre-planned takeoff or basic holding pattern will be done by a human operator over wireless.

**Notes:**

1. Total fuel load of parent fighter aircraft is of no concern
2. The drone mounts a forward-facing camera and a few sensors across the aircraft. The WSO gets a HUD and relevant data superimposed onto the view they receive from the drone. Their station is equipped to handle these drones.
3. WSO/back seater is pilot trained and qualified to fly these drones
4. The targets these drones will be firing at will range from anything involving primitive aircraft to 5th gen aircraft platforms. While the island in question may not be able to build high transistor density chips, that doesn't mean other islands cannot. There are enough flying based organisms that pose a threat to warrant this aircraft to be sortied against them as well.
5. Size can vary between something as small as a jet powered drone or as big as an F16.

Comment: You describe at least 3 different aircraft. The missile platform, the fighter, and the missile truck. But it is unclear which of the three is the drone.

Comment: Yes, radio controlled [model aircraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_aircraft) were common in the 1970s. Lots of people built and flew lots of them. And the military had radio controlled unmanned aerial vehicles since the 1930s; skipping over the Soviet efforts, you may want to read about the [Radioplane Company](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radioplane_Company).

Comment: @Daron The missile truck is the drone. The only other flying machine is the fighter aircraft. The fighter acts as a missile platform in the way that modern BVR centric aircraft do. I'll edit things to be more clear. There are only 2 flying machines for this question.

Comment: @AlexP The US' ww2 drones and anti ship missiles is what helped spur this question. The only concern I have is the ability for another pilot to control a jet fighter from a different aircraft altogether reliably. Especially in combat situations. Existing platforms like Loyal Wingman and FCAS extend systems seem to rely heavily on automating a lot of parts. Flight navigation is the big thing since they are using auto/ AI for navigation, whereas tv guided flight is significantly more manual.

Comment: Yes, there are limitations. The struggle of man to overcome the limitations of machinery is the subject of the story. Note that even with today technology nobody is deploying *fighter* UAVs in combat.

Comment: @AlexP I'm assuming slaving the fire control system of a drone and handing off missile control to the parent aircraft wirelessly was within the scope of the times?

Comment: The problem with *fighter* UAVs is communications delay. The entire point of military UAVs is that the pilots are far away; because if you are willing to put your pilots in danger, what is the point of having UAVs? Now if the pilot is far away, you will have a round-trip comms delay of several hundred milliseconds. Good luck flying a fighter aicraft in combat with such slow response.

Comment: @AlexP if you want to answer the question please do so in the answer box.

Comment: @Trioxidane: No, I do not want to answer the question.

Comment: How much of the lack of fighter UAV is due to resistance from the existing command structure (which for flying branches tend to be dominated by pilots and former pilots) rather than technical inability?

Comment: I would point out that even in terms of autonomous functioning, the early space missions (in the 60s) were largely controlled autonomously by onboard computers of the time (some of the designers even advocated for physically restraining the astronauts so that they wouldn't be inclined to interfere with the computers mid-flight and screw everything up).  UAVs were actually used in the Vietnam War, and a huge amount of development of basic military drone tech actually took place in the 80s.  "pre-2000s" tech is not nearly as primitive as you probably think it was.

Comment: the big problem such a platform has is that carrying said drone means the actual munitions it can deliver is extremally less than just carrying them in the original craft. It is a huge step up in complexity and failure points for, not just no benefit, but a large detriment in performance. you are building two planes to do the job of one much cheaper and simpler plane.

Comment: If you have two planes, two pilots, and two loads of missiles, then it doesn't seem to me that this plan really gains anything over just having two conventional one-man fighters.

Comment: @Cadence Technology is limited as well as production capabilities. Unlike the modern military industrial complex, the island is pouring all of its efforts into these aircraft and can still only field a single squadron by its first use. That said, their goal is for defending against longer and faster range assets that earlier generation equipment just can't deal with. The negative economics are worth it if the island can defend the production facilities as well as the farming areas. Just because the island is limited to pre 2000s computational technology, doesn't mean that other islands are.

Comment: The Predator drone dates to 1994. The earlier RQ-1 Pioneer dates to 1980.  Joseph Kennedy was killed in WWII flying a radio-controlled bomber that he was supposed to bail out of near the target while another remote pilot flew it to the destination by radio control.   The plane blew up when he tried to arm the bombs,  but it was a viable concept even in WWII.  And of course the V-1 flying bomb was a drone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**How feasible would it be to build and field such a drone that utilizes TV and radio command guidance against air targets without access to modern technology?**

Trivial.

In 1966, we landed the [Luna 9 probe on the moon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luna_9). What you are asking for is an order of magnitude less automation and complexity than that.

In fact, did you ever wonder why drones are called drones? I mean, a drone is a male bee. Turns out that the original "drone" was a DeHaverland DH82 Tiger Moth variant known as the ... [queen bee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Havilland_Tiger_Moth#Gunnery_target_drone). They built ~400 of these things back in 1935, a full 65 years before your required tech level. You can read about this in [significant detail here](https://www.n5490.org/V4760/Technology/Technology.html). Worth noting is the quote:

> Take-off and landing were completely automatic and not under radio control.

This was all done using gyros' and other analog tech.

Now you could argue that these don't quite meet your specification: they were piloted line of sight/autonomously by an operator on the ground. Well, good news! TV broadcast was alive and well at around the same time, coming into existance in the mid 1930's. Did they ever try to combine these technologies? Not to my knowledge. I don't see why they couldn't though.

In short: it is likely completely feasible to build a first-person-view pilotable drone using 1940's technology - let alone 2000's tech. Of course it's effectiveness is another question entirely, but at least you can build it!

---

My grandfather was into building and flying RC planes. I remember in ~2005 he showed me a video he had recorded by mounting a handled camcorder into one of his aircraft. He had made that video a few years earlier, which would put it pretty close to 2000. While it didn't transmit the video wirelessly, consumer level tech in 2000 was at the point where a consumer could do it, let alone the military.

Hackaday tells me full [FPV flight was achieved by hobbiests in the mid 1980's](https://hackaday.com/2020/03/13/an-epic-story-of-1980s-fpv-flight/), which doesn't surprise me much.